# Разделение Object

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
let obj = {"00:00":1, "00:10":5, "00:20":4,}
```

Мне нужно разбить его на:

```
{"00:00", "00:10", "00:20"}
{1, 5, 4}
```

Comment: может на ["00:00", "00:10", "00:20"]?

Comment: `Object.keys`, `Object.values`

Comment: @teran, `values` не подходит :) потому что второй результат `1,2,3` а не `1,5,4`

Comment: @Grundy есть шанс, что это опечатка автора )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
let obj = {"00:00":1, "00:10":5, "00:20":4,};

console.log(Object.keys(obj));
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```